# Oracle SQL - convert string into formula?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if there is a way to convert a string in Oracle SQL to a formula. E.g.

I have a connect_by string with a sys_connect_by_path that has asterics instead of commas or slashes, & I want to evaluate the formula. This is:

```
"=1*3.4693*48*3*1"
```

in a specific column. Of course, each row has a different calculation.

I'm expecting to have:
SELECT function('= 1 + 1') FROM  DUAL;

Comment: You can use `execute immediate`.

Comment: Can that be executed into a simple “select” query?

Comment: . . No.  You need to use PL/SQL.

Comment: Create a function passing in the formula and execute immediate within the function returning the result?  Looks like this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919168/invoking-a-function-call-in-a-string-in-an-oracle-procedure

Comment: No, I cannot use PL/SQL nor create any function or procedure. I need it to ve executable within a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the content of the expression, you may be able to do it with XML / XPath

```
select xmlquery(replace( '1*3.4693*48*3*1', '/', ' div ' ) 
      returning content ) .getNumberVal()   
from dual;
```

returns 499.5792

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp

Comment: Thanks. I'll try tomorrow first thing in my query.